# Refer to session variable without casting it to its type everytime

Tags: asp.net, session-variables

I have a session variable that is a class instance. I declared it in `Global.asax`:

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs when a new session is started
    Session["SiteVariables"] = new SiteVariables();

}
```

Now I need to refer to some of the members of this variable in several places of my solution but, as far as I understand, I have to do it this way:

```
SiteVariables objSiteVariables = (SiteVariables)Session["SiteVariables"];
Label1.Text = objSiteVariables.permiss;
```

I wonder if there is a way, e.g. setting up somewhere a static variable or something, that allows me just to do:

```
Label1.Text = objSiteVariables.permiss;
```

in any place of my project.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may create your own `helper` type/method.

```
public class Util
{
   public static SiteVariables Variables
   {
      get
       {
           return HttpContext.Current.Session["SiteVariables"] as SiteVariables;
        }
    }
}
```

And assign value to

```
Label1.Text=Util.Variables.permiss;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper for the session, which will allow type safe access like this:

```
public class SessionHandler
{
    public static SessionHandler CurrentSession
    {
        get
        {
            SessionHandler session =
              (SessionHandler)HttpContext.Current.Session["SessionId"];
            if (session == null)
            {
                session = new SessionHandler();
                HttpContext.Current.Session["SessionId"] = session;
            }
            return session;
        }
    }

    public SiteVariables SiteVariables { get; set; }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
// assign
SessionHandler.CurrentSession.SiteVariables = new SiteVariables();

// retrieve
SiteVariables objSiteVariables = SessionHandler.CurrentSession.SiteVariables;
```

This way you can add more sessions just by adding more property to the `SessionHandler` class.